# Load one reactjs app dynamically into another reactjs app

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a reactjs application which needs to load another application on demand which is also in reactjs (imagine its a 3rd party application), I read about react-loadable (https://github.com/jamiebuilds/react-loadable) but not sure if that helps my case. Can anyone provide some guidance on how should I approach this problem and what's the best solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

react-loadable allows you to load the components of your project dynamically ( using dynamic import syntax ). AFAIK you cannot load modules using react-loadable, which are not build statically by you ( i.e., when you build your bundles and publish ).

Your use-case seems more like you want to load a iframe. Just give the source of the 3rd party React /  application and it'll load in it's own sandbox.

Also the major problem here is that not all react apps are written and build the same way, so a direct integration is not possible.

Correct me if I missed something or am wrong. Hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response, but loading into an iframe is not an option here. I guess, I need to load the component dynamically as both the app are build by me. But what if I want to load a reactjs app in a normal jquery website. Can I do that?

Comment: Sure you can. Like any other client side framework, React just needs a mount node to stat. You can just pass a dom node ref to React-dom, and it'll render you react app. make sure before this, all your bundles are loaded.